# Heroku "No web processes running" error code 14 simple Python app

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I tried other answers but I can't find the solution for my problem. This is the error I get when deploying my app on Python:

```
021-09-02T17:12:50.556892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=adho-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=07e0ebc3-e4b3-4023-a43c-b862908f0132 fwd="93.44.81.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-09-02T17:13:15.920509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=adho-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=cec8df7f-7c6e-484a-ad93-78f5e6906813 fwd="93.44.81.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

`app.py` is

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,  external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server
```

In `index.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

My `Procfile` (I changed it multiple times but nothing worked):

```
web: gunicorn index:server
```

And `runtime.txt`:

```
python-3.8.12
```

Everything should be right, the app runs in local. `Requirements.txt` is set up, one of them is `gunicorn==20.1.0` as I've seen it being suggested online. I haven't used Flask.

Comment: What else do you have in `index.py`?

Comment: Change `gunicorn index:server` to `gunicorn index:app` because `app` is your server object.

Comment: I fixed mine by deleting and reinstalling db.sqlite3 yesterday

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using that. It's just some charts to display in a dashboard